# What is wrong with my scope below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing an active record scope in rails. I have the following sql:

```
SELECT user.roll_number, first_name, last_name FROM user 
  INNER JOIN classes ON user.roll_number = classes.roll_number
    AND classes.id IN #{id} ORDER BY(roll_number)
```

I wrote the scope in the user class, basically the tables are in the db2 database, so i wrote the scope as shown below

```
scope :by_id, lambda { |id|
  { select("user.roll_number, first_name, last_name")
      .joins("INNER JOIN classes ON (user.roll_number = classes.roll_number \
        and classes.id = #{id})")
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the scope? I am getting "unexpected keyword end error"

Comment: remove the `{}` inside the lambda block

Comment: @apneadiving What if i pass multiple ids? i am getting empty list, even though there are records for id 1 and id 2. i am passing id in the array form as id = [1,2]

Comment: Can you post more info about the error, eg the stack trace?

Comment: @MaxWilliams The error is resolved. I need to pass multiple ids, when i do that i am getting empty list even though there are records for ids  1, 2.

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the comment, you need to remove those `{}` braces.  I'm guessing the error you are seeing is because this:

```
{ select("...") }
```

Is interpreted as an instantiation of a Hash, with a key of `select("...")` and no value.  Ruby isn't happy with you.

Your follow-up:

> What if i pass multiple ids? i am getting empty list, even though there are records for id 1 and id 2. i am passing id in the array form as id = [1,2]

You made a SQL lambda, so it's all on you to make that SQL work.  A list of `[1,2]` is going to look like:

```
INNER JOIN classes ON (user.roll_number = classes.roll_number
  and classes.id = [1,2])
```

Will that work on your SQL DB?  Wouldn't you want to use `and classes.id IN (1,2)`?